# Jasmine testing with Initial Instantiated classes

Tags: javascript, jasmine, revealing-module-pattern

I'm using the revealing pattern and initial class instantation in my JavaScript. I am also using Jasmine to test this class, but need a way to reset the state of the myNamespace.myViewModel (this is a simple example, but imagine a complex view model with multiple variables) before each test is run.

Here's an example class:

```
myNamespace.myViewModel = (function(ko, $, window){
   var init = function(){},
       name = 'bob',
       nameSetter = function(value){ name = value; };
   return {
     Init: init,
     Name: name,
     NameSetter: nameSetter
   };
}(ko, $, window));
```

In Jasmine I start out with:

```
describe("VM Specs", function () {
    'use strict';
    var vm;
    beforeEach(function(){
       // the vm isn't re-created since it is a "static" class in memory
       vm = myNameSpace.myViewModel;
    });
    it("should set name", function(){
       vm.NameSetter('joe');
       expect(vm.Name === 'joe').toBeTruthy();
    });
    it("should have the default state, even after the other test ran", function(){
       expect(vm.Name === 'bob').toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you add an example of what you wanna test. Also what do you mean with reset the state, the states of `ko, $, window`?  I mean every new instance that you create of your model should have its own state.

Comment: @AndreasKöberle Thanks, I updated my question to attempt to make it more clear. Using the }(ko, $, window));  at the bottom of the myViewModel instantiates it when the javascript file is added to the page as <script src=.... Does that help at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Cause all that the pattern does, is to create a new object that has some variables bound in a closure. So even if you use this in your app you cant relay on the state of this object cause you cant create a new version of it. Also the word `class` isn't describing this pattern right as you can't create new instances from it. So you should ask yourself if this is the right pattern for you in this case.

Comment: That's what I was suspecting. Thank you for confirming me that.

Answer (score 0):

There is an `afterEach()` function. Works the same as `beforeEach()` but after the tests are run:

```
afterEach(function(){
    //reset the state here!
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I have the same problem as the class can't be re-instantiated since it is "static".

Comment: @Aligned then you may need to use a mock object to test the class

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, could you add a simple example? I've been using spyOn to mock out nested classes when I need to, but I want to call the physical class to test it's methods.